# How can I crash my display driver?

Tags: windows, drivers, display-driver

I would like to crash my display driver and have Windows recover from it.

When this happens in the wild it's accompanied by a status bar message such as:

> Display driver amdkmdap stopped responding and has successfully recovered.

Is there any way I can artificially cause this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to induce display driver crashes two different ways in the past:

1. Overclock your display device (GPU and/or video memory) too aggressively
2. Increase the temperature of your display device (use caution here!)

For the overclocking option, try increasing the clock on either the GPU or the video memory in small increments until a failure occurs. Often times this will result in either the display driver crashing and restarting (good in your case), or a system crash.

For the increased temperature option, I recommend that you find a way to blow warm or hot air locally onto the display device.
You could use a heat gun or hair dryer, and try not to heat up other components.

*!!! WARNING !!!*

Both of the above options have some level of risk associated, so make sure you're comfortable with that risk before trying.
That said however, I've never had any hardware failures due to either.

Comment: I was hoping for something a bit gentler but I suppose I'll have to roll up my sleeves :)